# Proper page aspect ratio?

Tags: margins

I have a question regarding the aspect ratio of my pages. I wonder if the given aspect ratio in my example is a good choice or if I should change any values to achieve a better print space. Experts, what do you think? :)

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}  \usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   \usepackage{mathptmx}  
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}   \usepackage{courier} 
\onehalfspacing \lipsum

\begin{document} \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{5pt} \setlength{\headsep}{15pt} \textheight =
635pt \setlength{\skip\footins}{10mm} 

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should stick to using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to set your page layout and avoid manual setting via `\setlength`.

Comment: @Werner saying in other words, remove all settings coming up after \begin{document} in the given MWE?

Comment: Yes, and add them as a collective `\geometry{paper=a4paper, margin=2cm, top=5pt, headsep=15pt, ...}`. Note that some of these might be contradicting, as knowing `paper` (and therefore `paperwidth`) and `margin`, you should be able to derive `textwidth` and therefore do not need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: probably not immediately relevant, but if you want a view on *traditional* page layouts, there's an article in tugboat by hermann zapf, [My collaboration with Don Knuth and
my font design work](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb22-1-2/tb70zapf.pdf), that touches on this.  (there are other articles that deal with this topic as well, but that's the one i remember most readily.)

Comment: Margins of `2cm` on a page of size `A4` makes for a rather wide text block. Can you make the margins a bit wider (and thus the text block a bit less wide), or can you go with a two-column layout?

Comment: I am flexible, I just want it to look more decent :)

I tried 2.5cm which was a good hint, if I try 3cm, LaTeX complains about problems with managing the floating objects.

Comment: I wonder if I should increase the top and bottom margins or not. What do you think?

Comment: @jens - could you provide a bit more information regarding the "problems with managing the floating objects"?

Comment: @Mico, my settings were wrong. If I change to [!htbp], everything works fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The traditional French `canon des ateliers` would give these  values for `geometry` on a4 paper (not taking into account marginpars, headers nor footers):

"ordinary" printing:

```
\geometry{textwidth=15.75cm, textheight=23.4cm, marginratio={4:6,5:7}}
```

"neat" printing:

```
 \geometry{textwidth=14cm, textheight=21.3cm, marginratio={4:6,5:7}}
```

"luxury" printing:

```
\geometry{textwidth=13.1cm, textheight=20.75cm, marginratio={4:6,5:7}}
```

You can see some explanations and details in my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183995/left-margin-wider-than-right-one/184017#184017).

Comment: @Bernhard: Thanks a lot for your response, very helpful. 1) I wonder what defines "luxury" printing as luxus? The higher amount of pages being printed? 2) If I want to take headers and footers into account, does it affect the given settings?

Comment: @Jens: 1) No necessarily. I think that, rather, it refers to very small printing runs — typically less than 1000, for which the amount of sheets of paper per book is unimportant, as you can have with poetry books, with engravings, unusual format, a beautiful vellum paper and the like. 2) I would say no, but large headers like fancyheaders' defaults should be avoided.

Comment: In your [answer to this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183995/left-margin-wider-than-right-one/184017#184017), you say the printing fraction of paper width reserved for the printing zone is most of the time 3/4 for ordinary printing. And indeed, in your code above `15.75cm/21cm=0.75` but `23.4cm/29.7cm=0.788`. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @Denis Bitouzé: I've just discovered your comment-question (well, maybe I had seen it before, but didn't have time to answer at the moment, then forgot…). The only reason is that everything is calculated w.r.t. the*width* of the paper sheet: its height is not taken into account.