# Are the default margins good enough for a book?

Tags: margins

I'm writing my Master's Thesis in LaTeX, using the `book`class (maybe I should have used the `memoir` one, but now it's too late) with the `twoside` option.

I thought the larger margin was that in the bindings side in order to balance the space lost because of the bindings. However, I've figured out it is exactly the opposite.

I'm afraid the text is going to seem very off-center. Do you think I should change the default margins for a Master's Thesis? Unfortunately, my university doesn't provide any template.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a FAQ the margins are wider on the outside edge of most publications (they are for thumbs, not for binding) If you want to make adjustment for binding then `geometry` package makes that easy, but you should still end up with wider margins on the outer edge

Comment: The outer margin has to be about twice as wide as the inner margin because when you open a book, you see `two` inner margins next to each other. You can take a look at my answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188612/proper-page-aspect-ratio/188619#188619) for a solution that uses the `geometry` based  on the traditional French ‘Canon des Ateliers’. It is for A4 paper, but is easy to adapt to Letter paper.