# Editing Margins

Tags: margins

Is it possible to the decrease the white space following the number of the page to be as in the screenshot below?! 
I use `\documentclass{article}` and I don’t provide the `geometry` package in the preamble .. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

or alternatively how to raise to the number of the page in the screenshot below something little above?! In such a case, I provide the following

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{footskip=15pt}
```

[image]

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is mandatory here to understand, how the page layout is defined. Why are you not using such a package like `geometry`, if you are not satisfied with the default page layout? The second paragraph seems to be rather the opposite than an alternative. Raising the footer with the page number enlarges the bottom margin that is already too large in the first paragraph, if I have understood it correctly.

Comment: No, the bottom margin, after using the geometry package, is turned from default to the margin you see in the second screenshot which is just the distance between the line in gray and the number of the page. This margin is not too large unlike the default one. What I ask is : "How can I increase the bottom margin in such a case ?  I wish I could clarified what I precisely mean.

Comment: Where is the MWE?

Comment: You might be interested by my answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188612/proper-page-aspect-ratio/188619#188619) which explains how French typographers calculate the margins according to the kind of document printing (ordinary, neat, luxury) to ensure the best possible readability. I give an easy adaptation to the `geometry` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  footskip = 0pt, % Remove skip between bottom of text block and footer
  bottom = \dimexpr\baselineskip+<len> % Distance from bottom of page to 
                                       % bottom of text block
}
```

The `\baselineskip` distance would show the footer (which includes the page number), while any value of `<len>` would increase the bottom margin (or you can just not use it).

Comment: This gives the error "Missing number, treated as zero".

Comment: @HusseinEid: What did you use for `<len>`? You need to specify a length (like `20pt`, say) or completely remove it.

Comment: This works fine, thanks for your help. Could you please take a look on my question here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338990/setting-the-layout-the-page-regarding-the-bottom-margins?noredirect=1#comment831559_338990 

Furthermore, what is the default distance from the bottom of the page to the bottom of text block ?!  @Werner