# Setting the layout the page regarding the bottom margins

Tags: margins

Is it possible to make a very little space (even if it is 1mm) between the last line in the page and the number of the page?. For sure, I need to do this for all pages not only for one page. Note that I’am using `\documentclass{article}` and I provide

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{footskip=15pt}
```

Here is a screenshot of how the bottom of the pages looks like. Your help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

The question in other words: Is it possible to get the number of the page slightly down ?!

Comment: isn't this a repeat of your previous question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338951/editing-margins

Comment: No, it is different, since otherwise I would never re-post it.

Comment: `\geometry{footskip=1mm}` should do it. However don't forget some letters have *descenders* (g, p,q,y, italic f), so 1mm might be a little just.

Comment: Where can I add this command ? In a line ? or you mean that I have to edit footskip=15pt  to footskip=1mm ?? @Bernard

Comment: Yes, in your preamble.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. This command causes in some pages combining between the number of such pages and the last line.

Comment: Neither question is very clear so hard to tell. It  is always best to include a complete document that shows the problem.

Comment: Could you provide more clarification please ? @JohnKormylo
and how I should use the command you wrote above ?

Answer (score 1):

The dimen register `\footskip` is the distance from the bottom (baseline) of the text area to the baseline of the footer.  But to prevent overlaps, LaTeX forces a minimum separation of `\lineskip` between the bottom of one line and the top of the next (as can be shown using `\footskip=0pt`).

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\newlength{\normalfootskip}
\setlength{\normalfootskip}{\footskip}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\footskip=\normalbaselineskip
\lipsum[8-12]
\footskip=\normalfootskip
\lipsum[12-16]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What \lipsum[1-8] precisely mean ?

Comment: It lists the first 8 paragraphs of some obscure latin text.  This is a standard way of filling a document for an MWE.

Comment: Ok 
Is there a way to move the number of the page a bit down for just one page or certain number of pages not the whole document ?.

Comment: Evidently so.  You might also look at the afterpage package (using \global\footskip=...).

Comment: @HusseinEid RTFM! -- Which is in the case of texlive or MikTeX easy: just type on the command line "texdoc packagename" and usually you'll get the PDF with the manual. E.g.: "texdoc lipsum" will display the manual of the lipsum package.