# footer options in Lyx

Tags: lyx, margins

How do i specify the following in Lyx, I have options for top margin, bottom margin, header height, inner and outer but not for the text height,width footer and footer separation which is specified by the guideline of the university.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of the geometry package, which is what LyX uses. You can also try and use the typearea package which works a bit differently (in that case do not use the geometry settings and write the options in the preamble).

Answer (score 1):

With geometry, you can simply compute the sum of leftmargin+rightmargin (inner+outer) and the sum top margin+bottom margin:

```
inner + outer + 160mm = 210mm,    top margin + bottom margin + textheight = paperheight.
```

Then you share these sums between top and bottom, or left and right. Unless otherwise specified by your university, in two-sided printing, typographical rules make inner margin about half outer margin (you must take into account the binding offset).

Alternatively, you can go into the preamble of your document and set the university specifications with

```
\geometry{textheight=245mm, textwidth=160mm, footskip=10mm, marginratio={4:6,5:7, bindingoffet=10mm}
```

The first ratio is `hmarginratio`, the second is `vmarginratio` (see more details in the geometry package documentation, §5).

*Note:* the *margin ratio* values given here are  for illustrative purposes. They're the values that fit the [French canon des ateliers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249190/recommended-margin-and-binding-offset/249263#249263).