# Article class geometry margins

Tags: margins, titlesec, geometry

**Question still unanswered**

I am trying to set up margins equal to 2.5cm all around the document.
With use of geometry (and fancyhdr) package which is:

```
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}
```

However i have noticed that by default top and bottom margins are slightly bigger than the left and right. Why is it like that and how to fix it?

Thus how to make those margins (all of them) identical and equal to 2.5cm?

My entire code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand*{\savedfootnotes}{}
\newcommand*{\resetsavedfootnotes}{\global\let\savedfootnotes\empty}
\newcommand{\tablefootnote}[1]%
{%
    \footnotemark
    \xdef\savedfootnotes%
    {\unexpanded\expandafter{\savedfootnotes}\noexpand\footnotetext{#1}}%
}
\edef\endtable%
{%
    \aftergroup\noexpand\savedfootnotes
    \aftergroup\noexpand\resetsavedfootnotes
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\endtable}%
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{bibentry}
 \nobibliography*
\usepackage{tocloft}
 \usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
    \posttitle{%
        \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.5em}%
}

\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftdot}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecdotsep{\cftdot}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pdftex,
pdfauthor={},
pdftitle={}]{hyperref}
%
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

 \linespread{1.5}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{ \thepage}
\setlength{\droptitle}{5cm}
\setlength\parindent{1cm}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesection{}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\@arabic\c@section.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\makeatother

\titlespacing*{\section}
{2.5cm}{0 pt}{1.5 pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{2.5cm}{1.5 pt}{1.5 pt}

\setcounter{section}{-1}


\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}


\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

title page


\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{\hfil 0 \hfil}
\newpage


\section{\hfil 1 \hfil}



\section{\hfil Bib \hfil}
\nocite{*}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibl2}

\endgroup
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Entire page looks like that:
[image]

At the top of it i have 0.1 inches more that on the left hand side. I want to have 1inch everywhere

---

**Edit by touhami**

Following comments it seems that the question is how to remove the gap between the frame and section title (this is related to `titlesec`)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{mwe}% just for the example

\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.SE! A minimal working example (MWE) is (nearly) always nice. Do you use headlines and footlines? Than you may have a look at the options `includefoot`, `includehead` and so on in the documentation of the geometry package.

Comment: Apologize, i am preparing and example just need to remove all personal informations from my document. Includefoot and infludehead are going to make this margin larger not smaller as i have checked.

Comment: It is a mess i know... It is a modification of some of my previous files thus not always consistent.

Comment: I calculated identical margins of 71.13188pt on all sides.

Comment: @JohnKormylo margins are not identical as somehow header and footer are included in such a manner that they make margins at top and bottom bigger.

Comment: Not relevant, but you should have `\noexpand\footnotetext{\unexpanded{#1}}` instead of `\noexpand\footnotetext{#1}`

Comment: try with `\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm,showframe]{geometry}`

Comment: @touhami ok fine, there is a gap between showframe and section title how to move section title to be adjacent to showframe?

Comment: Note, it is possible to move the PDF page origin.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183995/left-margin-wider-than-right-one

Comment: Maybe so, but is it OK without `\linespread{1.5}`? Which is probably not what you want, in fact. Use the facilities of `setspace` instead. Off-topic: `hyperref` should be loaded last.

Comment: You should hardly ever need `\newpage` in a document. Almost certainly, you are using the wrong class.

Comment: `titlesec` is responsible. Remove that code and there is no space.

Comment: Off-Topic: You should never need `\hfil` at the begin or end of `\section` commands. You should configure the headings instead. Note, that the `\hfil` will be at the table of contents and the running head too, unless you use the optional argument of `\section`.

Comment: The problem is related to `titlesec` package, do you really need to use it, (from your code it seems not necessary)

Comment: OK but when I remove titlesec package will still i have 1.5 linespread below section title and above and bellow subsection title?

Comment: yes of course, but if not just tell us what do you need exactly

Comment: I need 1.5 linespread below section title and below and above subsection title.

Comment: And after removing titlsec thus removing manually set value of linespread surrounding section titles and subsection titles i am left with linespread larger than 1.5

Comment: what about horizontal space before (at the left of) section title because you set `\titlespacing*{\section}
{2.5cm}{0 pt}{1.5 pt}` so section's title start at 5cm from the left edge is this what you want?

Comment: No in my original document this 2.5cm was change to 0

Comment: probably not relevant, but `\usepackage{titling}` appears twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove spacing above section in titlesec](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79232/remove-spacing-above-section-in-titlesec)

Comment: please see @egreg's answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79232/remove-spacing-above-section-in-titlesec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to not use `titlesec`. One can replace the stuff of this package i.e.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
```

and

```
\titlespacing*{\section}
{2.5cm}{0 pt}{1.5 pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{2.5cm}{1.5 pt}{1.5 pt}
```

with

```
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-1sp \@plus -1pt \@minus -.2pt}%
                                   {1.5pt \@plus .2pt}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-1.5pt \@plus -1pt \@minus -.2pt}%
                                     {1.5pt \@plus .2pt}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{mwe}% just for the example


\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-1sp \@plus -1pt \@minus -.2pt}%
                                   {1.5pt \@plus .2pt}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-1.5pt \@plus -1pt \@minus -.2pt}%
                                     {1.5pt \@plus .2pt}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}
\section{lipsum foo}
\lipsum[1]
\section{lipsum foo}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{lipsum foo}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]